# I want to write this cod e in android it is in MATLAB,

Tags: java, android, matlab

raww variable contain image.
    Code given below

```
raww = imread('try.bmp');
grayw1(:,:,3) = raww(:,:,3);
w1 = mean(grayw1,3)
g1=mean(mean(w1(61:120,61:120)))
imshow('try.bmp').
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: we're not going to do the work for you, sorry. But, for example, you can use openCV with Android.

Comment: bro i didn't want you to do work for me, i am facing problem that's why i asked.

Comment: Thanks question is solved i used split function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java libraries for linear algebra and matrices algebra for that. 
Or if you are trying to write greyscale a bitmap search for a java library that does that. Android most outer layer runs on Java language mostly

Comment: i want to process in rgb not in gray scale

Comment: it dosen't matter for the answer above you can use it for rgb as well look for a way to do it in Java